# How to access observedAttributes on Web Components

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, web-component, es6-class

So in Web Components you can use the [attributeChangedCallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Using_the_lifecycle_callbacks) once you have specified attributes to observe using:

```
static get observedAttributes() { return ['myAttribute']; }
```

How can I list/access the observed attributes from within my sub class?

```
class Foo extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this.observedAttributes); // <= undefined
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['bar'];
    }
}
```

Is this somehow possible? Is there a getter for the observed attributes?

I think the difficulty here lies in getting the `observedAttributes` of the parent class. Because if it was on the same class, you could just `Foo.observedAttributes` as @javimovi mentioned.

Here is a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/sonekedavo/edit?js,console) to play with.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `console.log(Foo.observedAttributes);`

Comment: Yes, that works! Thank you! However, I have a different setup actually. How to get the attributes from a parent class if it extends that one. I’ve edited the question to match that case, please have a look

Comment: This works ? `console.log(Bar.observedAttributes);`

Comment: Yes, that would work. But the problem is, I never know what the mixin class is called. It can be Bar, it can be Baz or C or MyClass or whatever

Comment: Found the solution thanks to your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it!: 
The `constructor` can be used:

> Returns a reference to the Object constructor function that created the instance object

Using the example mentioned before.

```
class Foo extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log(this.constructor.observedAttributes); // <= ['bar']
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['bar'];
  }
}
```